# How to cite critic reviews in-text but as standalone?

Tags: writing-style, quotations, citation

Let me explain after trying to Google, I cannot find information on how to quote a review/testimonial from a critic at a publication outside of the main text. The testimonial/reviews are listed at the end, sort of what you may see on posters for plays or customer reviews on a business flyer, but I don't know if that is the proper way. It's for a brochure, if that helps. Normally, I would incorporate a quote in-text, but in this case, I cannot.

Edit: I am finding customer testimonials have many examples such as here
[ex1](https://www.refworks.com/content/testimonials/default.asp), but in the case of critic review from a magazine for example, I'm lost.

Example:

> Main text
>   blah blah, CEO stated, "some quote" (citation here).
>   . . . 
>   end of main text
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>
> "Softest mattress ever! O-M-G!" (John Doe, *The Herald*, 2010).

or is it written like an epigraph?

> "The ennui killed me. Thumbs down!" --John Doe, *The Herald*
>   "Oh boy!" --Amazon Customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no requirement for a brochure to use any specific style.  You will want to be specific enough to convince the reader, and you will want to ensure that you don't go beyond "fair use" in quoting someone else's article or words.  Beyond that, you have a lot of freedom.

You might want to look at book blurbs, either on the back cover or inside, for possible examples, as these are in list form, possibly at the end of a text paragraph about the book.

Another source of examples would be non-fiction articles in the New Yorker. This magazine does a good job of documenting without the use of footnotes or anything that looks like a citation, thus not troubling the reader.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog on citing blog comments in APA Style](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2016/04/how-to-cite-a-blog-comment-in-apa-style.html) (a leading citation style in academia), mentions some key aspects of citation. The blog says the following should be included:

> Who: the author of the comment, or in your case testimonial.
>
> When: when was the comment or testimonial posted?
>
> What: indicate you are citing a testimonial on a certain page. In the blog this is done by stating: "Re: ".
>
> Where: preferably indicate the URL to the comment / testimonial, if that is not possible, you could settle for the URL to the page / blog itself.

A direct quote ([from the same blog](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2016/04/how-to-cite-a-blog-comment-in-apa-style.html)) on how such a reference would look (in APA style):

> "David, L. (2010, October 29). Re: E-ZPass is a life-saver (literally) [Blog comment]. Retrieved from http://freakonomics.com/2010/10/29/e-zpass-is-a-life-saver-literally/#comment-109178"

You can then use in-text citation to refer to this reference, this is done in the following way (the in-text citation is put in bold):

> *In this sentence I say something which should be attributed to a certain blog post* **(David, L., 2015)**